# Can I create parametrezed job into gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I need to create job into gitlab pipeline. I want trigger it manually and put into some variables for using into scripts. How can I do it? Can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be able to use parameterezed pipeline (not job) after gitlab 10.8 release. (May,22 2018)  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/44059

Comment: did u ever try using API for triggering pipeline?. I am talking about this particular API --> https://docs.gitlab.com/12.6/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline, Here, I am not sure how we can pass the variables while triggering pipeline, though the variable is an attribute here. If you have any example, please provide it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the solution, here is how we should pass it in the body:
 {
    "variables": [
        {
            "key": "Key",
            "value": "value"
        }
    ]
}